# Proof of the existence of a smallest topology such that all functions in a collection are continuous in Dudley's Real Analysis and Probability

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

I am having trouble comprehending the proof of corollary 2.2.7 (b) in *Real Analysis and Probability* by R.M. Dudley. The claim is as follows:

> If $S$ and $I$ are any sets, and for each $i \in I$, $f_i$ is a function from $S$ into $X_i$ , where $(X_i , T_i)$ is a topological space, then there is a smallest topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $S$ for which every $f_i$ is continuous. Here a subbase of $\mathcal{T}$ is given by $\{ f_i^{−1}(U): I \in I, U \in \mathcal{T}_i\}$, and a base by ﬁnite intersections of such sets for different values of $I$, where each $\mathcal{T}_i$ can be replaced by a subbase of itself.

The proof in the book is the following:

> Part (b), through the subbase statement, is clear from Theorem 2.2.6. When we take ﬁnite intersections of sets $f_i^{−1} (U_i)$ to get a base, if we had more than one $U_i$ for one value of $I$—say we had $U_{ij}$ for $j = 1, \dots k$, then the intersection of the sets $f_i^{−1}(U_{ij})$ for $j = 1, \dots , k$ equals $f_i^{−1} (U _i)$, where $U_i$ is the intersection of the $U_{ij}$ for $j = 1, \dots , k$. **Or, if the $U_{ij}$ all belong to a base $\mathcal{B}_i$ of $\mathcal{T}_i$ , then their intersection $U_i$ is the union of a collection $\mathcal{U}_i$ included in $\mathcal{B}_i$. The intersection of the $f_i^{−1}(U_i)$ for $i$ in a ﬁnite set $G$ is the union of all the intersections of the $f_i^{−1} (V_i)$ for $i \in G$, where $V_i \in \mathcal{U}_i$ for each $i\in G$, so we get a base as stated.**

Note:

- Theorem 2.2.6 states that: for any set $X$ and collection $\mathcal{U}$ of subsets of $X$, there is a smallest topology $\mathcal{T}$ including $\mathcal{U}$ , and $\mathcal{U}$ is a subbase of $\mathcal{T}$.
- A base for a topology $\mathcal{T}$ is any collection $\mathcal{B}\subset\mathcal{T}$ in the topology such that for every $V \in \mathcal{T}$, $V = \bigcup\{ U \in \mathcal{B} : U \subset V \}$.

It's the bolded part that troubles me:

1. The original statement only says that $\mathcal{T}_i$ can be replace by a subbase of itself. Why should we care about the situation where $U_{ij}$'s are members of a base $\mathcal{B}_i$ of $\mathcal{T}_i$?
2. As for why we get a base in the end: the set $\mathcal{V}=\{f_i^{-1}(U_i): U_i\in\mathcal{B}_i ;\mathcal{B}_i\text{ is a base of }\mathcal{T}_i; I\in I\}$ is a subbase that defines the smallest topology $\mathcal{T}$ containing it. Then any $V\in \mathcal{T}$ is some arbitrary union of finite intersections of sets in $\mathcal{V}$, i.e., some union of sets described in the last sentence of the bolded part, so these sets form a base for $\mathcal{T}$. Is this the right way to understand it?

Any help is appreciated!